# symfony2 doctrine:schema, remove entities and table

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-schema

i have generated some tables from entities using the :

```
   php app/console generate:doctrine:entity 

   php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

   php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

where can i find the generated schema file , describing all the table and fields that has been generated?
What's the best procedure to remove entities and table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` dumps the sql generated and executed in the command prompt, there is are no files generated with this command (asfar as I know).

A Doctrine table in the database should be seen as a collection of objects, if you want the table removed, remove the entity that holds the data and use the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.

If you want to change fields in the table, change the fields in the entity class holding the data and again use `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: thanx again... is there no files that gives an abstract of every tables and fields (of every possible bundles )? like it does exist in Ruby on Rails

Comment: You might want to take a look at DoctrineFixtureBundle (can't add link as im on my phone now)